# django is_valid() return false with no errors because of my html template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

when i add just `{{form}}` on my template, there is no problem. View is perfectly working and it is saving my data. But if i want to change my template as following, `is_valid():` returns `false`.

What is the difference between my following template and just added `{{formset}}` ? How can i return my following template to valid?

ERROR:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>projeKodu<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>projeAdamAy<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
NOT VALID
<ul class="errorlist"><li>projeKodu<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>projeAdamAy<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Thanks in advance...

My Views.py (it is working if i put just `{{formset}}` in my template

```
def addManmonth(request,id):
    AdamayFormset = modelformset_factory(AdamAy, fields=["projeKodu","projeAdamAy","tarih","adamAylar"], extra=0)
    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = AdamayFormset(request.POST,
        queryset=AdamAy.objects.filter(projeKodu_id__id=id,tarih__isnull=True),
        )
        for form in formset.forms:
            if form.is_valid():
                adamAy = form.save(commit=False)
                last_id = AdamAy.objects.last()
                new_id = last_id.id + 1
                print(new_id)
                adamAy.id = new_id
                adamAy.save()
        return redirect('core:index')
    else:
        formset = AdamayFormset(queryset=AdamAy.objects.filter(projeKodu_id__id=id,tarih__isnull=True),)
    return render(request,"core/addmanmonth.html",{"formset":formset})
```

My bad template :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{hidden}}
        {% endfor %}
    {{ form.tarih}}
    {{ form.adamAylar}}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

my forms.py

```
class AdamAyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AdamAy
        fields = ('tarih', 'adamAylar')
        widgets = {'tarih': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'id': 'tarih'}),}
```

My models.py

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projecalis = models.ManyToManyField(Personel, verbose_name=("Projede Çalışan Personeller:"),related_name="Proje_adam_ay", through="AdamAy")

class AdamAy(models.Model):
    projeKodu = models.ForeignKey(Projects, verbose_name=("Proje Kodu"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    projeAdamAy = models.ForeignKey(Personel, verbose_name=("Projede Çalışan Personel"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tarih= models.DateField(("Dönem:"), null=True, blank=True)
    adamAylar = models.DecimalField(("Adam Ay:"), max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.projeKodu},{self.tarih}"

    class Meta:
        db_table = "AdamAy"
        verbose_name_plural = "Adam Ay"
```

Data Table for AdamAy:
https://ibb.co/PD9t2yT

Edit:
Added forms.py and models.py , also edited views.py and my template regars to @ha-neul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
   {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{hidden}}
   {% endfor %}
   {{ form.field1}}
   {{ form.field2}}
   {{ form.field3}}
{% endfor %}
```

in your view, use `{'formset': formset}`, this will mak e your template code cleaner and more readable.

**UPDATE:**
Your forms.py.. no need to override init, also a couple of problems.

```
class AdamAyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AdamAy
        fields = ('tarih', 'adamAylar') # you only have these two fields come from user, right? 
        # exclude=() # do not use this  
        widgets = {'tarih': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'id': 'tarih'}), 'adamAylar': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Adam Ay Orani'}) 
}
```

**UPDATE2**
Put

```
if form.is_valid():


else:
   print(form.erros)
```

to see what is the error message. My guess is that the form is not validating. One possible reason is that in your form you defined two fields (tarih and adamAylar), but in your formset definition you have all 4 fields.

**Update 3**
The problem comes from the fact that you put two foreinkey fields in the formset (projeKudo, and projeAdamAy).

```
def addManmonth(request,id):
    AdamayFormset = modelformset_factory(AdamAy, fields=("tarih","adamAylar",), extra=0) #changed fields
    adamay = get_object_or_404(AdamAy, projeKodu_id=id, projeAdamy=request.user) # get your instance

    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = AdamayFormset(request.POST,instance=adamay)
        if formset.is_valid():
             
             formset.save()
             return redirect('core:index')
        else:
             print(formset.errors)
     else:
         formset = AdamayFormset()
     return render(request, "core/addmanmonth.html", {"formset": formset})
```

Comment: try to start with the simplest code in your template and add other stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my templates and views.py. What changes when i replace `{{formset}}` with `{{form.field}}`?

Comment: 1) can you be more specific? what do you mean? 2) is it working now?

Comment: if i use `{{formset}}` it is saving form. But when i render as above html, it is not saving. I followed django documents and i added `{{form.id}}` but still form is not saved. And also i tried  as you said. but it is not worked.

Comment: Did you put hidden fields part?

Comment: Yes, i added. Also i updated my question code as your instruction. Still there is no change. I couldn't save the form with render. Also i suspected my save method and i deleted id change stuff in my views.py and reorganized for just save method. it wasn't worked. it is still saving if i just render as `{{formset}}`.

Comment: the ```hidden``` part is covering ```form.id```, so you do not need to include ```form.id``` in template. If you view works with {{formset}} , it should work with current template. I could not find an error. Do you see anything comes out with ```form.erros```?

Comment: I added error text on my question. "Field is Required". And i added my M2M model and database.

Comment: Not sure what is your pk in your view. Updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your effort. When i update my fields as `fields=("tarih","adamAylar",)` the problem solved. Also I figure out that using `{{form.field1.as_hidden}}`  `{{form.field2.as_hidden}}` in template gived me same result.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks.